# Logic for values in JSF

Tags: java, jsf-2

I have simple problem in JSF 2.0 and I need advice what is better solution.  So, on my .xhtml page there is component  which has 2 values : Yes and No.

```
<h:outputLabel id=v1 value="#{someValue}"/>
<f:selectItem itemValue="0" itemLabel="#{msg['label.no']}" />
<f:selectItem itemValue="1" itemLabel="#{msg['label.yes']}" />
```

What I am trying to accomplish is get default value of f:select based on outputLabel.
For example: if outputLabel gets value: Amateur than default f:selectItem is 'Yes' otherwise is 'No' default. Is it better with some logic in backing bean or via rendering on xhtml page?

Comment: Why do you want to do that ? It looks a bit unconventional. If possible do you logic in the backing bean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set it in the property behind the input component's `value` attribute. You didn't show the complete code, but if it's for example a `<h:selectOneRadio>` like so

```html
<h:outputLabel for="foo" value="#{bean.label}" />
<h:selectOneRadio id="foo" value="#{bean.value}">
    <f:selectItem itemValue="0" itemLabel="#{msg['label.no']}" />
    <f:selectItem itemValue="1" itemLabel="#{msg['label.yes']}" />
</h:selectOneRadio>
```

then you should be setting the `#{bean.value}` in bean's (post)constructor. The complete picture is unclear, so here's a basic kickoff example instead of a well-suited solution:

```
private String label;
private Integer value;

@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    label = "Amateur";
    value = "Amateur".equals(label) ? 1 : 0;
}
```